# How to read blank cell column value of Excel in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using POI 3.10  for read excel (.xls) files in java. 
Suppose My cell value contains nothing/blank that time it skips that column and reads next column value but I want to read that blank value also as blank. 
eg.

```
header 1   header 2   header 3
mumbai                madras
delhi                 jaipur
```

In header 2 column there is no value 
I want mumbai null/"" madras delhi null/""  jaipur 
but my code gives this output- mumbai madras delhi jaipur 
My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fname = "D:/Vijay/xls/vijay/test.xls";
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);
        fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
        Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                String cellvalue = "";
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                    if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        cellvalue = myCell.getStringCellValue();
                    } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        cellvalue = "" + myCell.getNumericCellValue();
                    } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                        cellvalue = "" + myCell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                        cellvalue = "" + myCell.getCellFormula();
                    } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                        cellvalue = "";
                    }
                    System.out.println(cellvalue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: one solution is to read each cell using an index instead of a pointer. But in this case you have to define the max number of column to read

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)? Then trying what that suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. 
This is my working code to read blank and non-blank cell values from .xls file in java using POI 3.10

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Temp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> Temp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        int row = 0;
        String fname = "D:/Vijay/xls/vijay/ICICIPRUDENTIAL_D_000011161214_new.xls";
        try {
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             FormulaEvaluator formulaEval =
             workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            int rowEnd = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int rowStart = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
                Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                int lastColumn = r.getLastCellNum();
                int cols = 0;
                Temp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                    String cellvalue = "";
                    Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                    if (c == null) {
                        cellvalue = "";
                    } else {
                        if (r.getCell(cn).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            cellvalue = r.getCell(cn).getStringCellValue();
                        } else if (r.getCell(cn).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(r.getCell(cn))) {
                                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
                                Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(r.getCell(cn).getDateCellValue().toString());
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                cal.setTime(date);
                                cellvalue = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/"
                                        + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                                        + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            } else {
                                r.getCell(cn).setCellType(r.getCell(cn).CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                cellvalue = "" + r.getCell(cn).getStringCellValue();
                            }
                        } else if (r.getCell(cn).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                            cellvalue = "" + r.getCell(cn).getBooleanCellValue();
                        } else if (r.getCell(cn).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                            cellvalue = ""+ formulaEval.evaluate(r.getCell(cn)).formatAsString();
                        }

                    }
                    Temp1.add(cols, cellvalue);
                    cols++;
                }
                if (Temp1.size() > 0) {
                    Temp.add(row, Temp1);
                    row++;
                }
            }
             for (ArrayList al : Temp) {
                         System.out.println("Contents of temp " + al);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```